# click fuction of the javascript

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have an message page which shows your current messages. But the problem is that, it shows only one message, and that's the "newest" message. It shows the same  message at every messagetab i would press, no matther of what.

Here's the format of message tabs :

[image]

Here's how it sees if I press at first message tab:

[image]

My problem is that, message tabs won't "refresh" with the specific messages. It shows the same message at every message tab.

Javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.emailcontent input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).closest('.list-group-item').addClass('selected');
    } else {
      $(this).closest('.list-group-item').removeClass('selected');
    }
  });

  // Clicking a message
  $('.list-group-item > .media').click(function() {

    $('.list-group-item').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    });

    $(this).parent().addClass('active').removeClass('unread');
    $('.nomail').addClass('hide');
    $('.mailcontent').removeClass('hide');
  });

 $('.list-group-item > .media2').click(function() {

    $('.list-group-item').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    });



    $(this).parent().addClass('active').removeClass('unread');
    $('.nomail2').addClass('hide');
    $('.mailcontent').removeClass('hide');
  });

});
</script>
```

HTML

```
  <div class="mainpanel">
    <div class="emailcontent">
      <div class="email-options">

        <label class="ckbox">
        </label>
      </div><!-- email-options -->
      <div class="list-group">
        <div class="list-group-item unread">
          <div class="list-left">
            <label class="ckbox">
            </label>
            </div>
          <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left">
              <img class="media-object img-circle" src="../images/photos/user1.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <span class="pull-right">1 hour ago</span>
              <h5 class="media-heading">Sendername1</h5>
              <h5>Title1</h5>
            </div>
            <p>Hi. There's something wri..</p>
          </div>
        </div>

                <div class="list-group-item unread">
          <div class="list-left">
            <label class="ckbox">
            </label>
            </div>
          <div class="media2">
            <div class="media-left">
              <img class="media-object img-circle" src="../images/photos/user1.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <span class="pull-right">1 hour ago</span>
              <h5 class="media-heading">Sendername2</h5>
              <h5>Title2</h5>
            </div>
            <p>That's title2 that means yo...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- emailcontent -->

 <div class="contentpanel emailpanel">
      <h3 class="nomail">No mail selected</h3>
      <div class="mailcontent hide">
        <div class="email-header">
          <div class="pull-right">
            2 hour ago &nbsp;


          </div>
          <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object img-circle" src="../images/photos/user1.png" alt="">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">Sendername1</h4>
              to: me
            </div>
          </div><!-- media -->
        </div><!-- email-header -->

        <hr>

        <h3 class="email-subject">MESSAGE1</h3>
        <div class="email-body">
          <p>Text1</p>


      </div><!-- mailcontent -->

    </div><!-- contentpanel --><!-- mailcontent -->
     <div class="contentpanel emailpanel">
      <h3 class="nomail">No mail selected</h3>
      <div class="mailcontent hide">
        <div class="email-header">
          <div class="pull-right">
            2 hour ago &nbsp;


          </div>
          <div class="media2">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object img-circle" src="../images/photos/user1.png" alt="">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">Title2</h4>
              to: me
            </div>
          </div><!-- media -->
        </div><!-- email-header -->

        <hr>

        <h3 class="email-subject">MESSAGE2</h3>
        <div class="email-body">
          <p>That's message 2</p>

      </div><!-- mailcontent -->

    </div><!-- contentpanel --><!-- mailcontent -->
  </div><!-- mainpanel -->  
  </div><!-- mainpanel -->


    </div><!-- emailcontent -->
</div>
</div>
```

[Codepen.com, but there it won't select it all.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLLpvX)

Answer (score 0):

addClass('hide') and removeClass('hide') do not manipulate html content of a dom element, but simply change the display to none or to inline,..., so whenever you remove the class 'hide', you always see the same content. To remove html content you shoud use something like:

```
$(".email-body").empty(); 

$(".email-body").innerHTML = "<p>That's message 2</p>";

$(".email-body").append( "<p>That's message 2</p>" );
```

to remove div content and add your own content.

Comment: Then what about   $('.list-group-item > .media').click(function() {
  ?and the     $(this).parent().addClass('active').removeClass('unread');
    $('.nomail').addClass('hide');
    $('.mailcontent').removeClass('hide');
  });  shall remain or i should remove the entire javascript code?

Comment: Because, after clicking a new messagebar, I want to make to appear new HTML code @Saxon